# DM Problems That I need help with

Tags: dnd-5e

I am A new DM who has just started DMing a game of LMoP - this is my first game in which im DMing.  There are only 2 PCs right now. There is a 3rd PC who comes to play on-off.  (Is this ok?)

I have been Thinking of adding a NPC to the party to replace her when the 3rd PC's not there.

Another problem I have is that one of the PCs (Fighter) IS extremely bloodthristy who will do anything for that Sweet xp.  The Fighter is recklessly running into combat without thinking.

How can I get them to stop being Bloodthristy without ruining their fun?

My last problem (which is a minor one) is that we have arrived at a small river which we need to cross.  Our Wizard used *Ray of Frost* to freeze the river and cross it.  I allowed this. (Is that ok?)

Should I have given him an Inspiration point?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se. Please, take our [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). Our site works a little differently from what you might be used to. For starters, we use a One question = One question policy, so you will need to split your problems in a few posts. Also, we don't work with opinion-based questions ("should I give an inspiration point for X?" seems quite opinion-based, for example). Finally, we already have some of these problems addressed, at least partially if not completely. (Continues)

Comment: For example, about your bloodthirsty Fighter, this questions might help: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/8002/43856 or even https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2513/43856.

Comment: I recommend taking a look through [tag:absent-players] (https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89784/43856) and [tag:gm-techniques] and maybe [tag:new-gm] along with some keywords from your problems to check if the questions there already solve your problem(s) or not.

Comment: 1. Have you looked at the rules for [Ray of Frost](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf#page=99)?  2. Do you have the Dungeon Masters Guide?  If not, there are some questions here about Inspiration that might be useful to you. Welcome, and a tip of the cap for taking on the DM role.  Enjoy!  (I think you have two or three different questions here).

Comment: one of a number of [posts about Inspiration](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/67164/22566)

Comment: Also, the *ray of frost* part of this question is largely addressed by answers to [this other question.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90864/8610)